# Error 'initializer does not name a non-static data member or base class' when the initializer is the base class name

Tags: c++, inheritance, namespaces

I am facing the following problem. In the file *my_exception.h* I have defined my own exception class inheriting from `std::exception`:

```
// File "my_exception.h"
#include <exception>
#include <string>

namespace proj { namespace exception {

struct Exception : public std::exception {
    explicit Exception(const std::string& msg) noexcept : msg_(msg) { }

    inline const char* what() const noexcept override { return msg_.c_str(); }

private:
    std::string msg_;
};

} }
```

Then I defined a derived exception class called `BadParameterAccess` in another namespace, splitting the declaration and the implementation in a *.h* and a *.cpp* files, respectively:

```
// File parameter_exception.h
#include "exception.h"

namespace proj { namespace parameter {

struct BadParameterAccess final : public exception::Exception
{
    BadParameterAccess() noexcept;
};

} }

// File parameter_exception.cpp
#include "parameter_exception.h"

namespace proj { namespace parameter {

BadParameterAccess::BadParameterAccess() noexcept
    : exception::Exception("[BadParameterAccess] parameter not set yet."){ }

} }
```

I tried to compile this code using several compilers. 
With clang 6.0 I get the following error:

```
parameter_exception.cpp:7:18: error: initializer 'Exception' does not name a non-static data member or base class; did you mean the base class 'Exception'?
    : exception::Exception("[BadParameterAccess] parameter not set yet."){ }
                 ^~~~~~~~~
                 Exception
./parameter_exception.h:11:35: note: base class 'exception::Exception' specified here
struct BadParameterAccess final : public exception::Exception
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

g++ 7 gives an equivalent error, and Visual Studio 2017 gives the following:

```
parameter_exception.cpp(8): error C2039: 'Exception': is not a member of 'std::exception'
```

The code compiles perfectly when either:

1. in the file *parameter_exception.cpp* I specify the full path for the base class initializer (`proj::exception::Exception`), or
2. in the file *parameter_exception.cpp* I remove the namespaces from the base class initializer (`Exception`), or
3. in the file *my_exception.h* I remove the inheritance from `std::exception`, or
4. I rename my namespace `exception` in some other way.

As far as I have understood from the different errors I got, the compiler expects to find a member called `Exception` inside the class `std::exception` rather than inside the namespace `exception`, but I don't understand why this happens. 
Moreover, I would have expected the compiler to give me an error when I inherit from `exception::Exception` in the header file *parameter_exception.h* first, but it does not.

Can someone explain me the reason?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I *think* that deriving from `std::exception` introduces the name `exception` (unqualified) into the scope of `Exception`, but I have no idea where to look in the standard for this rule.

Comment: Is there a reason why tou use struct instead of class?

Comment: @anastaciu Not in particular, but I cannot see the reason why the use of a class instead of a struct should make any difference.

Comment: Could it be that you haven't #included your exception header?  `#include <exception>` and `#include "exception.h"` will both include the std::exception

Comment: @jiveturkey No, I have included the correct one, otherwise it would have not compiled when I specified the full name of the `Exception` class.

Comment: I was curious, are you using c++11 or later?

Comment: @anastaciu c++11

Comment: The second error makes suspicious that std::exception doesn't have a constructor.

Comment: Can you try out if `struct BadParameterAccess final : public proj::exception::Exception` works for you? (All I did was to add `proj::`, to make the namespace situation clear.)

Answer (score 1):

as @molbdnilo suggests there is a problem of name lookup. the problem is whith the name "exception" beeing used for namespace exception and the standard::exception struct. I removed code and comments from the code you posted.

```
namespace standard {
    struct exception{
        explicit exception() noexcept { }
    };
}
namespace exception {
    struct A: public standard::exception {
        explicit A() noexcept { }
    };
}
namespace parameter {
    struct BadParameterAccess final : public exception::A
    {
        //BadParameterAccess() noexcept : exception::A() { }; // KO
        BadParameterAccess() noexcept : ::exception::A() { }; // OK
    };
}

namespace standard1 {
    struct exception1{
        explicit exception1() noexcept { }
    };
}
namespace exception2 {
    struct A: public standard1::exception1 {
        explicit A() noexcept { }
    };
}
namespace parameter1 {
    struct BadParameterAccess1 final : public exception2::A
    {
        BadParameterAccess1() noexcept : exception2::A() { }; // OK
        //BadParameterAccess1() noexcept : ::exception2::A() { }; // OK
    };
}
```